# how to make array of objects in javascript using different objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a array which have objects .Actually I need to push object in array but before I have some conditions

- I have **a** array(a is array of objects) .I need to first remove all objects which have property **"hidden": true,** .I am able to do that like this
- I have another **b**(b is is array of objects).in which I need to collect values from that using parameter **fieldNameOrPath** .Those value which are deleted from first array which have **hidden :true**  need not to consider in second array .Not to check **fieldNameOrPath**.Or we can also delete those are deleted from first array using **fieldNameOrPath**

I trying to fetch values try to get expected result I fail to get

```
   var deletedfieldNameOrPath=[ ];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].hidden) {
            deletedfieldNameOrPath.push(a[i].fieldNameOrPath)
            delete a[i]
        }
    }
console.log(a);
console.log(deletedfieldNameOrPath);

var objectarray = []
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < b[i].columns.length; k++) {
        var obj = {};
        if (deletedfieldNameOrPath.indexOf(b[i].columns.fieldNameOrPath) == -1) {
            obj.b[i].columns.fieldNameOrPath = b[i].columns.value;
        }
        objectarray.push(obj)

    }

}
```

**Expected array**

```
 [{
    Type__c: "pqr",
    akritiv__So_Number__c: "a"
}, {
    Type__c: "Invoice",
    akritiv__So_Number__c: "-"
}, {
    Type__c: "inc",
    akritiv__So_Number__c: "c"
}, ]
```

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/93m4wbh1/

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of this for loop, try to use $.grep

Comment: how..?I use $.gep ? could you make fiddle

Comment: Your question is very unclear in current definition. You have provided existing algorithm and desired output. However please add input data and if possible clarify the logic of desired transformation

Comment: Observation: I see a minor issue in your code. Let's say the following condition fails: if (deletedfieldNameOrPath.indexOf(b[i].columns.fieldNameOrPath) == -1) {, still an empty value is inserted into the objectarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to what you want i think.

I did some minor changes:

- First i used splice instead of delete to make sure the object is
  removed from the array instead of leaving an empty record.
- Then i made sure the object is created and pushed for each column, not each record in each column.
- And at last I fixed a little bug preventing
  the values to be added to your object, using the [] (like on arrays).

```js
var a = [{
    "hidden": true,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "Name",

}, {
    "hidden": true,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name",
}, {
    "hidden": false,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c",
}, {
    "hidden": false,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c",
}];
var deletedfieldNameOrPath = [];
var collectNameOrPath = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i) {
    if (a[i].hidden) {
        deletedfieldNameOrPath.push(a[i].fieldNameOrPath)
        a.splice(i, 1);
        continue;
    } else {
        collectNameOrPath.push(a[i].fieldNameOrPath);
    }
    i ++;
}
console.log(a);
console.log(deletedfieldNameOrPath);


[{
    Type__c: "pqr",
    akritiv__So_Number__c: "a"
}, {
    Type__c: "Invoice",
    akritiv__So_Number__c: "-"
}, {
    Type__c: "inc",
    akritiv__So_Number__c: "c"
},

]
var b = [{
    "columns": [{
        "value": "a0RK0000002l3AB",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Name"
    }, {
        "value": "Sun Life Financial",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name"
    }, {
        "value": "pqr",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c"
    }, {
        "value": "a",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c"
    }]
}, {
    "columns": [{
        "value": "a0RK0000002l3ac",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Name"
    }, {
        "value": "Scottish Power",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name"
    }, {
        "value": "Invoice",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c"
    }, {
        "value": "-",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c"
    }]
}, {
    "columns": [{
        "value": "a0RK0000002l3aC",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Name"
    }, {
        "value": "FirstEnergy",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name"
    }, {
        "value": "inc",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c"
    }, {
        "value": "c",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c"
    }]
}]


var objectarray = []
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var k = 0; k < b[i].columns.length; k++) {
        if (deletedfieldNameOrPath.indexOf(b[i].columns[k].fieldNameOrPath) == -1) {
            obj[b[i].columns[k].fieldNameOrPath] = b[i].columns[k].value;
        }
    }
    objectarray.push(obj)
}

console.log(objectarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to delete elements from the array.
Try this.

```
var a = [{
    "hidden": true,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "Name",

}, {
    "hidden": true,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name",
}, {
    "hidden": false,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c",
}, {
    "hidden": false,
        "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c",
}];

var collectNameOrPath =
    a.filter(function(o) { return !o.hidden })
     .map(function(o) { return o.fieldNameOrPath });


console.log(collectNameOrPath);

var b = [{
    "columns": [{
        "value": "a0RK0000002l3AB",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Name"
    }, {
        "value": "Sun Life Financial",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name"
    }, {
        "value": "pqr",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c"
    }, {
        "value": "a",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c"
    }]
}, {
    "columns": [{
        "value": "a0RK0000002l3ac",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Name"
    }, {
        "value": "Scottish Power",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name"
    }, {
        "value": "Invoice",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c"
    }, {
        "value": "-",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c"
    }]
}, {
    "columns": [{
        "value": "a0RK0000002l3aC",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Name"
    }, {
        "value": "FirstEnergy",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__Account__r.Name"
    }, {
        "value": "inc",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "Type__c"
    }, {
        "value": "c",
            "fieldNameOrPath": "akritiv__So_Number__c"
    }]
}]

var nameOrPathValues = b.map(function(o) {
  var result = {};
  o.columns.forEach(function(c) {
    result[c.fieldNameOrPath] = c.value;
  });
  return result;
});

console.log(nameOrPathValues);

var objectarray = nameOrPathValues.map(function(o) {
  var result = {};
  collectNameOrPath.forEach(function(name) {
    result[name] = o[name];
  });
  return result;
});

console.log(objectarray);
```